# Custom UIViewController animations and modal presentation modes

Tags: ios, ipad, animation, uiviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

Using custom `UIViewController` animations on iPad when `modalPresentationStyle` is `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` or `UIModalPresentationPageSheet` displays a grey box after the animation is complete.

(The grey box is actually a `UIDropShadowView`.)

I should note, the custom animations work fine - the view controller is placed where this grey box is, and then as soon as they are marked complete, something adds this box.

Is there a workaround? Or is only `UIModalPresentationCustom` supported for custom animations?

[image: dumb grey box]

Comment: I'd love to find an answer to this as well :/